# Select most recent qualified type within a date range

Tags: mysql, max

I have a data set that contains IDs, Status Dates (ordinal) and Status Types.

- Status Types are `Open`, `Transfer` or `Close`
- The Primary Key is a combination of ID and Status Date. So an ID will have multiple
  records.

I am trying to select a subset of data that contains IDs within a date range where the most recent Status Type is Open or Transfer.

```
SELECT id, 
       status_date, 
       Date_format(Str_to_date(status_date, '%Y%j'), '%m/%d/%Y'), 
       status_type
FROM   my.TABLE 
WHERE  ( ( ( status_type = 'O' ) 
            OR ( status_type = 'T' ) ) 
         AND ( status_date <= 2012182 ) )
```

Should I use `MAX(Status_Date)` or the `LAST(Status_Date)` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LAST` is not a valid MySQL function, so `MAX` would be the appropriate function. You also don't need all those parentheses.

```
WHERE  ( status_type = 'O' 
          OR status_type = 'T' ) 
       AND status_date <= 2012182
```

You can alternatively use `IN` to specify a list for `status_type`.

```
WHERE  status_type IN ('O', 'T') 
       AND status_date <= 2012182
```